# What is SOAP injection?

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap

I am new to WCF and recently came to know that Web services are prone to many kind attacks and one among them is 'SOAP injection'.

1.Can anyone explain to me what an SOAP injection means?
2.At which Transport level does this attack occurs?
3.Does using of https protects the service completely? 
4. Is there any way we can validate the incoming soap messages in WCF ?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score -1):

Regarding question 1, "What an SOAP injection means".

With most questions of the form, "what is XYZ", you can and should just google it.

http://www.google.com/search?q=SOAP+injection+attacks

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Well I have already done that, but I couldn't get a satisfactory explanation to it from any of the results returned.Thats why I decided to post here.I really want some hints on rest of my questions. :(

Comment: @wizzardsz: possibly you give up too fast, like, if you don't see THE ANSWER in boldface 72-point font at the very top of your screen? the second hit that google serves me is "Dana Epp's ramblings...", referring to an SPI whitepaper on SOAP data injection. It's freely available as a PDF (although the link given by Dana Epp is stale). You should be able to find it in about a minute or so of effort. If not, ask again.